# UDEV to detect bluetooth joystick

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, udev, xinput, joystick

Using Ubuntu MATE 16.04

My issue is I have a bluetooth joystick however when it connects, it controls my mouse. More specifically, when I play a game, the cursor goes all over the screen. To fix this I open up terminal and execute:

```
xinput set-int-prop "Amazon Fire Game Controller" "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

Then I can take my "normal" mouse and move the cursor off of the screen. This is fine until I quit playing and then the joystick disconnects from lack of activity. When I press a button on the joystick and it pairs up with the bluetooth, I have the cursor problem until I do the `xinput` thing again.

My goal is to use UDEV to detect the bluetooth joystick connecting and run a script executes the `xinput`.

I have used `udevadm info -e` to see if I could capture info but there is too much info for me to make sense of it.

Right now I have:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/90-joystick.rules


ENV{ID_NAME}==”Amazon Fire Game Controller", ENV{HID_UNIQ}=="00:bb:3a:ec:80:6d", ACTION=="add", RUN+=”sudo -u johndoe -c /home/johndoe/systemscripts/joystick.sh %p”
```

`/home/johndoe/systemscripts/joystick.sh` (chmod 777 so anyone can run it for now)

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput set-int-prop "Amazon Fire Game Controller" "Device Enabled" 8 0
date > /tmp/joystick.txt
```

and any change I make I execute:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

However the joystick still acts as a mouse when paired and the script never runs (`/tmp/joystick.txt` never gets created)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Ok I accomplished my goal, but not in a precise method.
I watched /var/log/syslog which shows my bluetooth activity when I activate the bluetooth joystick

```
Dec 14 06:27:16 SuperComputer kernel: [ 1908.362129] input: Amazon Fire Game Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.8/2-1.8:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:41/0005:1949:0402.000F/input/input22
Dec 14 06:27:16 SuperComputer kernel: [ 1908.365299] hid-generic 0005:1949:0402.000F: input,hidraw2: BLUETOOTH HID v0.21 Gamepad [Amazon Fire Game Controller] on 00:0c:76:46:da:d9
```

Now I made a change to my udev rule:

**#1 /etc/udev/rules.d/90-joystick.rules (changed)**

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="hidraw", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/bin/sudo -u johndoe /home/johndoe/systemscripts/joystick.sh"
```

Since I only have 1 bluetooth device I am concerned with, I am only looking for hidraw activity. I will look for 16.04 udev info and see if I can fine tune this to look for its address but for now, I am satified.
Also I removed passing the %p to my script

**#2 /home/johndoe/systemscripts/joystick.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export DISPLAY=:0.0

/usr/bin/xinput > /tmp/joystick.txt 2>&1
whoami >> /tmp/joystick.txt
/usr/bin/xinput set-int-prop "Amazon Fire Game Controller" "Device Enabled" 8 0
```

In my joystick.sh, I had to export display as xinput needs this to function correctly.

Now I am set!!!! When I click a button or move the joystick, once it establishes connection to bluetooth, I no longer have a crazy cursor to content with.

If anyone can give me clues or refer me to good udev info so I can fine tune this, I'd appreciate it

Hope this helps someone